# Notifications of new Facebook comments on a per user basis

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Facebook comments plugin as the commenting mechanism on a site.  I know how to receive new notifications of each comment as the admin, however I would like the user that created the page that the comment is on to receive a notification as well.  Users login / register with Facebook and they can post certain items on the site.  Those items belong to them and have their own individual comment box.  On the page I can easily grab the Facebook user ID of the page author and we have their email stored.  Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would answer this myself.  Its actually quite easy.

Facebook allows you to subscribe to comment events.  So in your Facebook javascript init:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '###########',
        frictionlessRequests: true,
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });

     FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
         if(response.authResponse)
           window.location.reload();
     });


     FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(resp) {

        $.ajax({url:baseUrl+'/user/facebookcommentcallback/',

                data: {
                    list_id: 'Whatever ID'
                },

                success: function(data) {

                }
            });
        });
```

So in the call back I just have an ajax function that takes the id of current page, looks it up, finds the page owner, and sends an email to them whenever a comment is posted on that page.  EASY!